# Using Webview2 in Visual C++ application on Windows 7 fails

Tags: c++, windows, webview2

I use a Webview2 NuGet package to include a Webview2 control in a Visual Studio 2022 C++ project. The project is Microsofts own WebView2GettingStarted project. I use the newest available Microsoft.Web.WebView2 NuGet package (1.0.1370.28). On the client machine(s) I have installed the newest Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime.

When I run the application on any Windows 10 machine (with Webview2 runtime installed) the application works fine, but when I run the application on Windows 7 it fails with the error dialog:[image: The procedure entry point EventSetInformation could not be located in the dynamic link library ADVAPI32.dll]

If I use an old version of Microsoft.Web.WebView2 NuGet package namely version 1.0.1054.31 then the application works on both Windows 7 and 10, however I dont like to be limited to an old version.
WebView2 is supposed to run on Windows 7.

Does anybody have any ideas to a solution?

Comment: The newer package is using `EventSetInformation` which needs: _"Minimum supported client Windows 8 [desktop apps | UWP apps]"_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntprov/nf-evntprov-eventsetinformation

Comment: @Richard Critten: Thanks for the reply! It makes sanse that the application does not work on Windows 7 with your explanation.    
However, I think that it is wrong of Microsoft to claim that WebView2 supports Windows 7, when only old versions of the Microsoft.Web.WebView2 package actually runs on Windows 7.

Comment: You might want to read _"Windows 7 support ended on January 14, 2020"_ https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020-b75d4580-2cc7-895a-2c9c-1466d9a53962  So I don't think they care.

Comment: @Richard Critten: You are probably right :) Unfortunatedly for us, some of our clients still use Windows 7. Thank you again - it is nice to have the reason for the problem in writing from MS themselves...